# Создать XML в GWT

Tags: xml, gwt, java

Есть ли в GWT либа для создания xml файлов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочтите это. В самом конце рассказано, как лепить дерево:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML.html

Comment: лепить))